# Can awk accept two arguments?

Tags: awk

I'm new to this and a little in the dark, so if my title is off the mark please correct me. I'm trying to set a variable in awk from one file, and then invoke the script on a different file.

ex:

- sqlinsert writes to fields.txt

I execute:

cat textfile | ./awkscript

awkscript pulls 'fields' var from fields.txt while running on textfile

Here is what I have. I'm using getline, and that isn't what I'm looking for. I want it to grab the value from the first line of a separate file.

```
\#!/opt/local/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN { 
    printf "Enter field lengths: "
    getline fields < "-"
        print fields
}       

BEGIN {FIELDWIDTHS = fields; OFS="|"}
{
        {       for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) sub(/[ \t]*$/,"",$i)        }

\#       {       for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) sub(/^[ \t]*/,"",$i)        }

        print
}
```

Comment: please consider adding some sample input, expected output, current output to your question, other wise we'll be playing 20-questions with you ;-) Also, I don't see in your code that you're using field.txt. Good luck.

Comment: I don't know how to use field.txt, that's the problem. All I want it to do is set the fields variable to something like "10 5 7 8 18 7 6" or whatever value it finds on the first line of fields.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was looking for was this:

cat textfile | generic.awk -v fields='10 1 21 21 4'

The `-v` option can also be used multiple times:
cat textfile | generic.awk -v field1="10" -v field2="1" -v field3="21" -v field4="21" -v field5="4"